# Unable to configure the kendo editor applied on a div element without a toolbar

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I applied kendo editor on a div element rather using textarea as it's giving some issues in iPad. Now, I don't want the editor to have toolbar to format text.

I tried applying styles as none & set tools to an empty array but still the toolbar appears with a draggable button in it.

```
<div id="targetdiv" contenteditable="true" style = "resize: none;width: 
  100% 
!important; height:150px; max-height:150px;max-width: 100% !important;">
</div>

<script>
$("#targetdiv").kendoEditor({
    tools: []});
</script>
```

The toolbar appears though the editor it initialized with no tools, as in image below.

[image: empty toolbar with draggable icon]

Approach 1: **(Not working)**

```
<style>
.k-editor-toolbar
{
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

Approach 2: **(Not working)**

```
$('.k-editor-toolbar').hide();
```

Approach 3: **(partially works)**

Added a select event but still the toolbar appears for an instant and then disappears.

```
 $("#targetdiv").kendoEditor({
    tools: [],
    //Fires when the Editor selection has changed.
    select: function (e) {
        let editor = $("#targetdiv").data("kendoEditor");
        editor.toolbar.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the toolbar define an empty tools in the KendoUI editor initialization:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
// Empty tools so do not display toolbar
tools: [ ]
});
```

If you want to disable the edition, you should use:

```
$(editor.body).attr('contenteditable',false);
```

you can try this one as well

```
.k-editor-toolbar
{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it shows empty toolbar with draggable icon. Please check the image attached in question itself.

Comment: Can you try to inspect the UI and find the parent class. What we can do is, We have to find the parent class of kendo control, then you can either set from jq $(".parentclass").hide() or style the class.
I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I have to **subscribe for the open event of the editor toolbar and prevent its execution.** This resolved my issue.

```
let editor = $("#targetdiv").getKendoEditor();
editor.toolbar.window.bind("open", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```